# MongoDB get data from object in document using java

Tags: java, mongodb, object

I have the following document in my database:

```
_id: ObjectId('63a73aec1afb1e4de760d9de')
uuid: "71e5db4e-ab05-4de2-9238-5660474c5156"
coins: 0
level: 1
currentXp: 1
upgrades: Object
   durability: 0
   luck: 1
```

Now I want to get the data from the object. I tried to get the int from durability by doing this:

```
public static int getDurabilityLevel(UUID uuid) {
    Document filter = new Document("uuid", uuid.toString());

    int durabilityLevel = Main.getInstance().getDataConnection().getCollection().find(filter).first().getInteger("upgrades.durability");

    return durabilityLevel;
}
```

I also want to chance the value of the luck integer. But if I try to chance it, the durability integer disappears. I used this to chance the value:

```
public static void setLuckLevel(UUID uuid, int level) {
    Document filter = new Document("uuid", uuid.toString());

    Document foundDocument = Main.getInstance().getDataConnection().getCollection().find(filter).first();

    if(foundDocument != null) {
        Document updateValue = new Document("Upgrades", new Document("luck", level));
        Document updateOperation = new Document("$set", updateValue);

        Main.getInstance().getDataConnection().getCollection().updateOne(foundDocument, updateOperation);
    }
}
```

I hope anyone can help me with this simple problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now I could fix the problems. Here are my solutions:

This is my way to get data from the object:

```
public static int getDurabilityLevel(UUID uuid) {
    Document filter = new Document("uuid", uuid.toString());

    Document document = Main.getInstance().getDataConnection().getCollection().find(filter).first();
    Document object = (Document) document.get("upgrades");

    int durabilityLevel = object.getInteger("durability");

    return durabilityLevel;
}
```

And this is my way to chance data in the object without deleting the other values:

```
public static void setDurabilityLevel(UUID uuid, int level) {
    Document filter = new Document("uuid", uuid.toString());

    Document foundDocument = Main.getInstance().getDataConnection().getCollection().find(filter).first();

    if (foundDocument != null) {
        Document updateValue = new Document("upgrades.durability", level);
        Document updateOperation = new Document("$set", updateValue);

        Main.getInstance().getDataConnection().getCollection().updateOne(foundDocument, updateOperation);
    }

}
```